# MongoDB Aggregation PHP, Group by Days

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the db with the following format

```
Array
(
[_id] => MongoId Object
    (
        [$id] => 53f4bf0e8db0d31b0ba802df
    )

[userSession] => 580929792589634763f964479eee8721
[pageEnteredDate] => 1408548587
[pageLeftDate] => 1408548622
[userName] => User 1
[userId] => 33657
[pageView] => monitoring patients
[pageActions] => []
[pageTag] => 1-3-16-131-315
[timeSpent] => 35
)
Array
(
[_id] => MongoId Object
    (
        [$id] => 53f3d7008db0d33e61cae841
    )

[userSession] => e04e5081c9482654030bacf3c8c90b21
[pageEnteredDate] => 1408488536
[pageLeftDate] => 1408489216
[userName] => user 2
[userId] => 4278
[pageView] => Surgery Staff
[pageActions] => [["BUTTON","Comment",1408488701],["A","Discussion",1408488712]]
[pageTag] => 1-3-5-148
[timeSpent] => 680
)
Array
(
[_id] => MongoId Object
    (
        [$id] => 53f3d7008db0d33gj1cae841
    )

[userSession] => e04e5081c9482654030bahjhc8c90b21
[pageEnteredDate] => 1408488536
[pageLeftDate] => 1408489216
[userName] => user 3
[userId] => 428
[pageView] => Surgery Staff
[pageActions] => [["BUTTON","Comment",1408488701],["A","Discussion",1408488712]]
[pageTag] => 1-3-5-148
[timeSpent] => 680
)
```

pageEnteredDate is the date that i want to use

I want to group the data by pagetag and day. I mean on one day i should get the same pageTag only once.

So, from those 3 arrays it should display only 2 because 2 have the same pageTag and are on the same day.

Thanks

***code used

```
$result = $this->collection->aggregate(
array(
    array(
        '$group' => array( 
            '_id'=> array( 'pageTag' => '$pageTag','day' => array('$subtract' => array('$pageEnteredDate', 86400))),
            'timeSpent' => array( '$sum' => '$timeSpent' ),
            'lastView' => array( '$max' => '$pageEnteredDate' )
        )
    ),
    array('$skip' => 0),
    array('$limit' => 20)
)

);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "date" values appear just to be numbers derived from epoch timestamps ( without the milliseconds ). But all you really want to do here is apply [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) via the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/), and a little date math to group by "day":

```
$result = $collection->aggregate(array(
    array(
        '$group' => array( 
            '_id' => array(
                'pageTag' => 'pageTag',
                'day' => array(
                    '$subtract' => array(
                        '$pageEnteredDate',
                        array('$mod' => array(
                            '$pageEnteredDate',
                            60 * 60 * 24
                        ))
                    )
                )
            ),
            'timeSpent' => array( '$sum' => '$timeSpent' ),
            'lastView' => array( '$max' => '$pageEnteredDate' )
        )
    )
));
```

That basically says to group on both the "pageTag" values and using the "pageEnteredDate" to apply the math that essentially rounds the timestamp to the current day, so all values within the same day are the same.

You haven't said exactly what it is that you want to "group" here, so the examples are given of applying a [**`$sum`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) to the "timeSpent" value and using [**`$max`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) to identify the last timestamp value recorded on that day.

You can use any of the ["grouping operators"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-group/) in this way to suit your needs

Comment: Thanks for your help. I get this error: exception: the $subtract operator requires an array of 2 operands. If i replace the mod function with a value is working.

Comment: @Teodor Arggh! I am not a fan of PHP array notation. Generally if I have to do this I prefer something sane like JSON and then decode that and possibly manipulate. Rare case where I did not check before submitting. Missing a wrapping `array()` method around `$mod`

Comment: One more question, if i want to show more fields? i am trying with $project but isn't working array(
                        '$project' => array(
                            'pageEnteredDate' => 1,

                        )
                    ),